# I want the use to be able to input their first and last name. Then I want to change their input so that it will come out as last, first

Tags: java

So far I have the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Names {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String name = input.next();
        changeNameFormat(name);
    }

    public static void changeNameFormat(String name) { 
        System.out.println(name.substring(0,20));
    }
}
```

I am not sure, but I think I need to use an array, however I am unsure of how to go about this seeing as I will not know what the user input will be every time.

Example of what I want to happen:
User inputs:

> John Smith

I want the program to output it as this:

> Smith, John

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking maybe giving a sample input output will help

Comment: Okay, I added an example at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you ask the user to enter the first name and last name with a comma separation.

For example: FirstName,LastName

In this case you can use comma as the delimiter for identifying first name and last name.

```
public static void changeNameFormat(String name) { 
    String [] splitName = name.split(",");
    //splitName[0] holds first name and splitName[1] holds last name
    System.out.println(splitName[1] + ", " + splitName[2]);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a space as a delimiter?

Comment: Some times user will have a first name with two words. In that case it fails

Answer (score 0):

An easier way without manipulating / splitting **one** `String` is to use the `Scanner`'s default delimiter (whitespace):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
// assuming the input consists in name surname[return]
String name = input.next();
String surname = input.nextLine();
System.out.printf("%s, %s%n", surname.trim(), name.trim());
input.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in the `changeNameFormat`

```
System.out.println(name.replaceAll("^(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)$", "$2, $1"));
```

Also, remember to change the `input.next()` to `input.nextLine()` to be able to read multiple words in one line. For more detail on the regex, please refer to the following link:

https://regex101.com/r/sA4xJ5/2